# Android byte[] to image in Camera.onPreviewFrame

Tags: android, image, byte, decoding

When trying to convert the `byte[]` of `Camera.onPreviewFrame` to `Bitamp` using `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` gives me an error `SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null`

Following is my code:

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
}
```

Comment: Meybe it will be useful to someone. Look at my solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298699/onpreviewframe-data-image-to-imageview/34438806#34438806

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer after a long time. Here it is...

Instead of using `BitmapFactory`, I used my custom method to decode this `byte[] data` to a valid image format. To decode the image to a valid image format, one need to know what picture format is being used by the camera by calling [`camera.getParameters().getPictureFormat()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getPictureFormat%28%29). This returns a constant defined by [`ImageFormat`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html). After knowing the format, use the appropriate encoder to encode the image.

In my case, the `byte[] data` was in the `YUV` format, so I looked for `YUV` to `BMP` conversion and that solved my problem.

Comment: Can you please tell me how do you query the **camera.getParametrs()** , how i can check my image format?

Comment: @Numair http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getPictureFormat()

Comment: It's also possible to call http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFormat(int) but not all cameras support all formats.  `NV21` or `YV12` are apparently universally supported and the default is `NV21`.

Comment: @ArslanAhmad not sure where the code is now. Consider looking at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/YuvImage.html (may be helpful)

Answer (score 34):

This has been hard to find! But since API 8, there is a YuvImage class in android.graphics. It's not an Image descendent, so all you can do with it is save it to Jpeg, but you could save it to memory stream and then load into Bitmap Image if that's what you need.

```
import android.graphics.YuvImage;

@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    try {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();
        YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(),
                size.width, size.height, null);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getPath() + "/out.jpg");
        FileOutputStream filecon = new FileOutputStream(file);
        image.compressToJpeg(
                new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), 90,
                filecon);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toast toast = Toast
                .makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), 1000);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very hacky solution. Saving to a jpeg and then immediately decoding it? I think I'd rather use a custom YUV function.

Comment: @Timmmm I agree that a custom YUV function, which are not hard to come across, would be better than saving and loading via jpeg. But this is sill best if saving to jpeg is all you want to do. I think it's a shame `YuvImage` is not an `Image` descendant, then it wouldn't need any hacking or self YUV coding.

Answer (score 7):

Since Android 3.0 you can use a `TextureView` and `TextureSurface` to display the camera, and then use `mTextureView.getBitmap()` to retrieve a friendly RGB preview frame.

A very skeletal example of how to do this is given in [the TextureView docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html). Note that you'll have to set your application or activity to be hardware accelerated by putting `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the manifest.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this:
This example send camera frames to server

```
 @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        try {
            byte[] baos = convertYuvToJpeg(data, camera);
            StringBuilder dataBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            dataBuilder.append("data:image/jpeg;base64,").append(Base64.encodeToString(baos, Base64.DEFAULT));
            mSocket.emit("newFrame", dataBuilder.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.d("########", "ERROR");
        }
    }

};


public byte[] convertYuvToJpeg(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21,
            camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width, camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height, null);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int quality = 20; //set quality
    image.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width, camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height), quality, baos);//this line decreases the image quality


    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```