# Byte array image to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays

I'm trying to convert the byte array image to bitmap, but after conversion it gives me black image, why?

```
// Camera arg conversion to Bitmap
                Bitmap cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0,
                        arg0.length);
                 Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap(cameraBitmap.getWidth(),
                 cameraBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

I want the camera image converted to bitmap. Any suggestion. Thanks in advance!!

```
07-17 02:22:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(398): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-17 02:22:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(398): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: only support ImageFormat.NV21 and ImageFormat.YUY2 for now
07-17 02:22:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.graphics.YuvImage.<init>(YuvImage.java:82)
07-17 02:22:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at com.exercise.AndroidCamera.AndroidCamera$4.onPictureTaken(AndroidCamera.java:225)
07-17 02:22:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.hardware.Camera$EventHandler.handleMessage(Camera.java:320)
07-17 02:22:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 02:22:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-17 02:22:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-17 02:22:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 02:22:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-17 02:22:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-17 02:22:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-17 02:22:18.149: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the camera's image format is not ARGB_8888. Most likely it's something like YUV420p or maybe even the JPEG-compressed data.

First of all, determine what is your case.

You have two options: for YUV (which is an interleaved format) use some conversion format and for JPEG create a memorystream for your arg0 array and read the Bitmap from it.

There are similar questions here: [BitmapFactory null issue in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364933/bitmapfactory-null-issue-in-android)

And there is even a solution here: [Android byte[] to image in Camera.onPreviewFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212531/android-byte-to-image-in-camera-onpreviewframe)

EDIT: you just have to mangle the bytes in your array a little.

This [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) explains how to convert the YUV422/420 to YUY2, required by the Android API.
Search for the "Y'UV422 can also be expressed in YUY2 FourCC format code" substring there.

Comment: i appreciate the way you explained the issue. I tried to use the second link, which gives me force close error when i pressed the save picture button. Check my edited question for logcat

Comment: I figured out the issue, i was working **onPicturetaken()** (such an idiot for not mentioning that), so it doesnot need that conversion. The above mentioned can work in **onPreview()**. Thanks @Viktor Latypov for your perfect ans