# OnPreviewFrame data image to imageView

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, yuv

i'm trying to get the byte[] from the preview of the camera, convert it to bitmap and display it on a imageview with imageView.setImageBitmap()

i've managed to start the preview and display it on a surfaceView, but i don't know how to convert the byte[] data (that comes in Yuv format i think) in a RGB bitmap to display it on a imageView.

the code i'm trying is the following:

```
camera = camera.open();
parameters = camera.getParameters();
camera.setParameters(parameters);
surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
camera.setPreviewCallback(this);
camera.startPreview();
```

and the preview callback is this

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    int width = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
    int height = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;
    ByteArrayOutputStream outstr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height); 
    YuvImage yuvimage=new YuvImage(data,ImageFormat.NV21,width,height,null);
    yuvimage.compressToJpeg(rect, 100, outstr);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(outstr.toByteArray(), 0, outstr.size());
    imgView1.setImageBitmap(bmp);        
}
```

The preview works but the imageView remains empty

Any idea?

Comment: where you set imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp); ?

Comment: After Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(outstr.toByteArray(), 0, outstr.size());

Comment: make sure outstr.size()!=0!!?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer... however, how should i check this?

Comment: see outstr.length() or some other function for check size in ByteArrayOutputStream class in doc

Comment: Hey..@PitrHey.. i am developing an CustomCaemra App. i had same Problem.i also want multiple camera Preview into single Activity[Like in GridView].Please help me How can i achive this..i already asked question but no one gave me answer....Here is my Question Link.......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392791/how-to-apply-custom-filters-in-a-camera-surfaceview-preview

Comment: i googled it and tried more tutorial's,libraries[grafica too].but i did not achive this type of Preview[Multiple Cmaera Preview]. i found more problem's same as my problem in Stackoverflow.but same as my Question no one gave answer's.Please see this Link i want this type of View....http://i.stack.imgur.com/WYHuj.jpg

Comment: Please help me if you know .when You will be free..God Bless You...Thanks..

Answer (score 35):

It is possible you did not open the Camera in the UI thread. However, you need to ensure setImageBitmap is called in the UI thread:

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    int width = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
    int height = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;

    YuvImage yuv = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(), width, height, null);

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    yuv.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 50, out);

    byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

    MyActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loopback)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hey @Bla...i am developing an CustomCaemra App. i had same Problem.i also want multiple camera Preview into single Activity[Like in GridView].Please help me How can i achive this..i already asked question but no one gave me answer....Here is my Question Link.......http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392791/how-to-apply-custom-filters-in-a-camera-surfaceview-preview

Comment: i googled it and tried more tutorial's,libraries[grafica too].but i did not achive this type of Preview[Multiple Cmaera Preview]. i found more problem's same as my problem in Stackoverflow.but same as my Question no one gave answer's.Please see this Link i want this type of View....http://i.stack.imgur.com/WYHuj.jpg