# Can I have CameraPreview and ImageView in same activity in full screen?

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera

I want to show the captured image after somebody clicks it. The current approach I'm using is creating a new Activity for ImageView after saving the picture to a SD card but this is taking a lot of time and a lag is visible.

After the ImageView activity, I want to again switch to CameraPreview activity. Could this be done using a single activity and replacing the preview with ImageView in the same activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course this can be done with one activity.

- Initially show the *CameraPreview* and hide the *ImageView*
- When the user "clicks it"

  - stop the preview
  - take the picture and show it in the *ImageView* (for example [like shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20888671/6742849))
  - hide the *CameraPreview*, show the *ImageView*
- When the user taps some other button (or whatever)

  - start the preview
  - hide the *ImageView* show the *CameraPreview*

Comment: what do you mean by take the picture and show? You mean save it and then load it from there?