# Get colour of particular pixel from live camera preview - Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, mobile, camera, ionic3

I'm trying to recreate functionality which is similar to this: [image: http://tvbarthel.fr/CameraColorPicker/resources/Screenshot_2015-05-17-17-04-27_framed.png] using Ionic.

The screenshot demonstrates an inner circle on a live camera preview which grabs the colour along with an outer circle which shows the colour of the pixel currently being looked at.

I have the live camera preview working with overlays however I don't know where to begin with grabbing a colour from a particular spot on the screen.

I understand you can take a photo and grab the colours that way but that isn't the functionality I was after, I was looking at something which allows me to see the results in real-time.

Can this functionality be achieved? If so, how can I do this?

Comment: If you already have a working preview then you can also analyze the frames which are delivered (e.g. `onPreviewFrame()`) and you can get the color of a specific pixel like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7807442/6184203). And you can get the touch coordinates on the image/frame with something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11312423/6184203). Have fun implementing! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can this functionality be achieved? If so, how can I do this?

I faced similar situation in my Application so thought it will be helpful.

I was creating a Cordova-Angular Hybrid app for real time image processing:

1. Open the front camera and show the different objects in-front of camera.
2. If object found in the dictionary then display the success message and stop previewing.

Here were the Steps:

1. Created new **Cordova plugin** that start the **camera in  previewMode**. For getting the current image of the preview you need to override the **onPreviewFrame** method.
2. Get the buffer the image and convert it and Match it.
3. Based on success/fail call the callBack Method.

**Now I think in your case Step-1 will be same with some additional Steps.**

1. Create new **Cordova plugin** that will start the **camera in  previewMode**. For getting the current image of the preview you need to override the **onPreviewFrame** method.
2. Override the **onTouchEvent** method to calculate the point inside the ImageView and in same time calculate the pixel of the frame inside **onPreviewFrame** method.
3. After getting the result just update the view with result.

**Also I think the main part in this ionic app is still native.Cordova will just do  the bridging.**

References:

1. http://topandroidphones1.blogspot.com/2012/04/get-color-on-specified-location-from.html
2. [OnPreviewFrame data image to imageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298699/onpreviewframe-data-image-to-imageview#20888671)
3. [Get the touch position inside the imageview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312128/get-the-touch-position-inside-the-imageview-in-android#11312423)
4. [How to Get Pixel Color in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807360/how-to-get-pixel-colour-in-android#7807442)
5. [Capturing the Camera Preview with a PreviewCallback](https://bytefish.de/android/)